How to change icons for executables in the Dock?
I recently switched to Ubuntu on my laptop because of performance issues and noticed something strange. Some of my apps don't have their icons in the Dock. I have read about .desktop files, but they didn't help. How can I change icon for those specific apps so it will show in dock and Alt+Tab too?


I think when you say DOCK you mean DASH although both names might be right.
If you right click on the icons in the DASH you can unpin the icon from it.
To add an icon select ShowApps menu (bottom left) and find the icon you want to pin to the DASH. Rick click on it and select pin to dash. But note: When you do this it will vanish from the ShowApps menu
To get it to show in the ShowApps and DASH see the example of the Skype icon in the anser to the following link.
Skype icon changed after update

If you want to add an icon to the Gnome menu (DASH ShowApps etc) copy the .desktop file you have created to either of the following depending on whether is an apt or snap and you want it to be global or just local to the current user: -
~/.local/share/applications/
/usr/share/applications/
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications

You might need to restart gnome which I do by just logging out and back in again.

If you want to create or customize a desktop file see the answer at the following link: -
.desktop file won't run

In Ubuntu 24.04, an app may show its app icon in the app grid and search result, when trying to launch it. Meaning the app icon file is correctly installed on your system. However, after launched the app window, Ubuntu Dock shows a gear icon instead.
This is because the window created by the application is not associated with the shortcut used to start the application. In Ubuntu 22.04 and earlier, you’ll get duplicated app icons on the dock. However, in Ubuntu 24.04 it falls back to the executable icon (the gear icon) instead
In this case, user can simply add StartupWMClass string in the associated .desktop config file, and set the value to the class name of the open windows to fix the issue.
To find the wmclass do the following:-
Run the offending application.
Then ALT F2
lg  #GNOME’s integrated debugger
Click the Windows button.
Make a note of the offending apps WMclass
ESC to exit the integrated debugger.
Then add the following to you .desktop file
StartupWMClass=[Name-from-debugger]
It should now all work correctly.
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2024/04/missing-icon-dock-ubuntu-2404/

Thing is that :

I don't want them to be pinned to the DOCK/DASH, they are apps I open only once a week, if not less.
Even when I pin them to the dock they don't open as supposed to. They open new executable, with wrong icon (ShowApps shows "Free Download Manager", executable "fdm")

image

@Eclassic I have added more details to the answer. If you have not put the .desktop file in the right directory then the gnome icon app will not pick it up (see answer). If there is a mistake in the .desktop  file it might also not find the icon. (See the link in the answer).

@Eclassic Sorry, I missed the image link at the end of your comment. I have added another section on adding WMClass data to the .desktop file in order to complete the association between the .desktop start file and the actual application. (I currently can't get this to work in all cases though.)
